# Does using checkinstall instead of make install allow to easily remove dependencies?

Tags: compiling, dependencies, source, uninstall, checkinstall

I'm very new to Linux, so please excuse any *normie* errors/misconceptions. I want to learn how to build programs from source, but I'm having a hard time understanding how dependencies are managed when building.

I have read that using `checkinstall` instead of `make install` will package a built-form-source program so that uninstalling it is easier (easier as in being able to remove it with a package manager).

Does that mean that uninstalling a program [that was installed with `checkinstall`] will also make it's dependencies 'removable' through the package manager (E.g. `apt autoremove`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the dependency from repositroy using `apt` or build using `checkinstall` then yes. `checkinstall` doesn't install directly to your system like `make` do. It pretend to the installation that it is getting installed, tracks what files are generated, generate a deb, rpm or such a package which is installed by the package manager. Then you can uninstall it using the package manager. If you think you install dependency with `make` and actual program with `checkinstall` and later uninstall dependency using apt then it is not.